# Add completion suggestion 'nameof' for parameter with Resharper

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, resharper

I would like to add a completion suggestion of `nameof` to a parameter in a method.

**The method:**

```
public static class Ensure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// throws <see cref="ArgumentException"/> exception if string is null or empty.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">string to check its content.</param>
    /// <param name="name">name of parameter passed.</param>
    public static void StringNotNullOrEmpty(string value, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty", name);
        }
    }
}
```

When typing `Ensure.StringNotNullOrEmpty(testString, <...>)` I would like to get the `nameof(testString)` suggestion for `<...>`. The above method doesn't suggest the `nameof` (Worse still, after typing 'n' I only get suggestions as `null`, `new`). The `nameof(...)` is necessary so I get the correct `ParamName` in the `ArgumentException`.

On the site of Resharper it says that `ArgumentNullException` makes use of the `nameof` suggestion by using the `InvokerParameterNameAttribute` (source: [Resharper InvokerParameterNameAttribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#InvokerParameterNameAttribute)).

**Attempt:**
So I installed the nuget package in my project: [JetBrains.Annotations 10.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations) and changed the method as followed:

```
public static class Ensure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// throws <see cref="ArgumentException"/> exception if string is null or empty.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">string to check its content.</param>
    /// <param name="name">name of parameter passed.</param>
    public static void StringNotNullOrEmpty([CanBeNull] string value, 
        [NotNull] [InvokerParameterName] string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above attempt is still not giving me the suggestion of `nameof` when I've typed: `Ensure.StringIsNotNullOrEmpty(testString,`.

Some other thing I found was the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx). But this only gives me the name of the calling method as a `string`.

I also looked into some repo's on GitHub, and could only find solutions the same way as my attempt.

One reason I can think of is when having two `string` parameters in a method with an `InvokerParameterNameAttribute` defined on the latter, it could be confusing for Resharper.

Is it possible to add the `nameof` suggestion for a parameter in a method? And how can I achieve this with the above method?

**Additional info:**
I have VS2015 + Resharper 2016.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually that works (but not as you intended). it will not suggest as soon as you type `,`... it will only suggest you to use `nameof` expression when you fully type name of argument in form of string instead of using nameof expression.

```
static void Caller(string arg)
{
    StringNotNullOrEmpty(arg, "arg"); // only now resharper suggests to use nameof.
    StringNotNullOrEmpty(arg, "something else"); // now resharper complains about unknown argument name.
}
```

You can [submit feedback](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Providing_Feedback.html#d136592e154) on resharper to actually implement the behavior you want.

Also if you type `""` the cursor will move to middle of double quotes and resharper suggests name of available parameters.

BTW you can always comment your code that can be useful for every future readers

```
/// <summary>
/// throws <see cref="ArgumentException"/> exception if string is null or empty.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">string to check its content.</param>
/// <param name="name">name of parameter passed.</param>
public static void StringNotNullOrEmpty([CanBeNull] string value,
    [NotNull] [InvokerParameterName] string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Resharper does indeed suggest the `nameof` after I wrote the method call, but I would like to see the `nameof`suggestion while I am typing it. As when writing `throw new ArgumentNullException(`, it directly suggests `nameof(value)`. Is that even possible in my method? And as for the documentation of this method, I excluded this from the post but updated it in the post.

Comment: @FirstOrGoat The behavior you want cant be achieved as far as i know. You can suggest and submit feedback regarding this behavior, they may work on it or give you a solution

Comment: Thanks! I will make this suggestion on Resharper and will update my post when I get their feedback.